# How to consume rest API with username and password using multipart/formdata encoding and using POST method

Tags: c#, restful-authentication

I am trying to consume this API: https://clbeta.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/pincodes/.
I am able to to get output from postman tool. but unable to get results from C# application which I have created. I am new to these concepts please help me with this.

I have also tried using basic authentication method but unable achieve results.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace Ecomapisample
{

    public enum Httpverb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

    public enum AuthenticationType
    {
        Basic,
        NTLM
    }
    class Ecomapi
    {
        public string EndPoint { get; set; }
        public Httpverb HttpMethod { get; set; }
        public AutheticationTechnique AuthTech { get; set; }
        public AuthenticationType AuthType { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        public Ecomapi()
        {
            EndPoint = string.Empty;
            HttpMethod = Httpverb.POST;
        }




        public string MakeRequest()
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint);

            request.Method = HttpMethod.ToString();

            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            string AuthHeader =  System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UserName + ":" + UserPassword));
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,AuthType.ToString() + AuthHeader);
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error code in response recieved: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }

                else
                {

                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (responseStream != null)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
                }
            }
            return strResponseValue;
        }
    }
}
```

//the code from postman tool looks like this.

```
var client = new 
RestClient("https://clbeta.ecomexpress.in/apiv2/pincodes/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------ 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"username\"\r\n\r\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n------ 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"password\"\r\n\r\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n------ 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The output I need is the JSON Output. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the API was written but you might want to try telling it what you accept. Some APIs do not default to JSON so you have to signal them to by providing another header.

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```